# Can 230 voltage device use 220 voltage?

Tags: voltage, appliances

I have 230 voltage appliances, those are gifts from Germany. I live in Vietnam where the voltage is 220 V.

So can I use those appliances safely in my country?

Comment: Yes. 230V devices are rated for 230V±10%, so they operate as designed with anything from 207V to 253V. Out of that band, the appliance may not work.

Comment: Also, the mains frequency in both Germany and Vietnam is 50 Hz, so that will not present a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EU, it was not always the 230VAC, but also 220VAC. Then some decades ago they changed to 230VAC, but still the old machines are 220VAC and they are all working.
http://www.schneider-electric.co.uk/en/faqs/FA144717/

> Currently, ALL Western European supplies are classified 230VAC. In
>   reality there is no 230VAC supply unless you create one locally.
>   230VAC was a “standard” created during European "harmonisation" to
>   give a single voltage standard across Western Europe, including UK and
>   Irish Republic.
>
> Although the ideal would have been to have a single voltage there were
>   too many political, financial and technical obstacles to reduce UK
>   voltage to European levels or to increase European voltage to UK
>   levels, so a new standard was created to cover both. This was achieved
>   by changing the tolerances of previously existing supply standards. UK
>   voltage  to 240VAC + 6% and - 10% and European to 220VAC +10% and -6% 
>   (thereby creating a manageable overlap) and we would call these two
>   combined 230VAC, despite the fact that nobody was intentionally
>   generating at 230VAC!

You see, it's just politics. Some they have still 220VAC and UK has still 240VAC, but we can say it's 230VAC with high tolerance window.